# Confluent local installaton failure

Tags: installation, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I m trying to install Confluent local on my ubuntu 20. When I start the local all the services are  up

[image]

but when i try to run the control center it fails and a successive call to check the status show some of the services are down

[image]

I am following the quick start guide https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html#ce-quickstart

not sure how to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

You should troubleshoot with `confluent logs`

You also will need at least 8GB of RAM for all services to start successfully.

---

I suggest you use `systemctl` after installing with `apt-get`, or at least use `docker-compose` or Confluent Helm Charts / Strimzi to start all services... `confluent` command is not used in a production envrironment, so wouldn't be good to get used to using it, IMO